# Let k be a natural number. What is the probability of it being equal to a random number in group?

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions, random-variables

**We have 6 groups:**

A takes values from [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

B takes values from [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

C takes values from [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]

D takes values from [0, 1, 2, 3]

E takes values from [0, 1, 2]

F takes values from [0, 1]

Each variable takes one of those values randomly, and independently from each other. What is the probability that k, is equal to A, the probability that k is equal to B, and so on for each of them. Given that $1\leq k \leq 6$.

For the first group I noticed the probability of it being each value is $1/7$.

For the second one, $1/6$.

.
.
.

For the last one $1/2$.

Unfortunately I am stuck since I don't know how to compare them to k.

As you can see, K can take any value from $1,...,n$. Where $n$ is the number of sets.

Comment: I don't quite understand the problem. Why don't you simply divide the number of occurrences of each element, by the total number of elements in all the groups combined? For example, $1$ occurs $6$ times out of $27$ elements, so the probability of $k=1$ is $\frac{6}{27}$.

Comment: Is $k$ an integer random variable taking the values $1$ to $6$ with equal probability? If not, then you need more information about $k$

Comment: @barakmanos The problem is a bit different, I am not supposed to find the probability that k = 1, but the probability that k = A, the prob that k = B, etc. So in this case the probabilities should be done relaying on the fact that k can take any val from 1 to 6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the first group, there are $6$ choices for $k$ and $7$ for $A$. So the total number of cases is $42$. The number of successful cases is $6, $ for $\{k=1,X[A]=6\}\cdots$ Therefore the probability is $\frac{6}{42}=\frac 17$ for the first group. Following the same logic, group $2$ has chance $\frac{5}{36}$, and group $3$ has chance $\frac{4}{30}=\frac{2}{15}$

The probability of $k$ equaling each set is therefore the product of all the chances.

Comment: Ok so given that I have 42 choises for the first one, the probability that k is equal to 1 in the first one will be 1/42?

Comment: No. Assume that the element selected from $A$ is $1$. Then $k=1$ is a solution to $X[A]=k$. Apply similar logic with $X[A]=2\cdots6$, and you get 6 successful outcomes.

Comment: I am having a bit of trouble understanding it... do you know a way I could represent the probability in terms of k and n? n being the number of sets. I seem to follow some of your logic but this part confuses me {k=1,X[A]=6}. My confusion arises because mainly I have to find the probability that k is NOT in the first 5 sets, but it is in the last one. That is why I wanted to start by asking this.

Comment: That means the successful outcomes are $k=1,X[A]=1,k=2,X[A]=2\cdots k=6,X[A]=6$. The combined probability is simply $$P_{a}^{a_n}P_{b}^{b_n}\cdots P_{f}^{f_n}$$
Where $P_k$ is the probability of $k$ equaling some integer in $k$, and $n_k$ is the number sets $k$.

Comment: Thanks, how could I use this to find the probability that k equals F but doesn't equal A, B,C,D, and E? Would this be P(k!=A or B or C or D or E)P(k = F)? If so how do I get the first group, it is taking me a year with so many equations that I can't reduce :(

Comment: @JOX if you want to find that it equals F but not any other, think about the probability that $k\neq A,B,C,D,E$. For example, $k=1$ has probability $\frac 67$ in A, $\frac 56$ in B, etc of not equaling it. The answer would then be $$\frac 67 \times \frac56 \times \frac 45 \times \frac 34\times \frac 23 = \frac 27$$(Most numbers cancel out). Then multiply by $\frac 12$, the probability for F. Therefore your initial assumption is correct but is actually relatively simple to compute.

Comment: Actually, what happens when k is a constant, not a random variable? How does this change things?

Comment: @JOX if $k$ is a constant and not a random variable, it still does not matter because we do not know what $k$ is, as it can be any integer $1\le k\le 6$

Comment: wouldn't it be 1/12 not 1/2?